# How to import <paper-textarea> for Polymer 3.x?

Tags: javascript, typescript, polymer, polymer-3.x

I tried the following terminal command:

```
npm install --save paper-input
```

then got the following error:

[image]

A key statement in that error message is

> npm WARN paper-input@3.0.2 requires a peer of react@>= 15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Also, it seems to deposit the repo in

node_modules > paper-input (like a 2.x element)

instead of:

node_modules > @polymer > paper-input (like a 3.x element should)

What's going on here? All I want to do is install `paper-input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the following work?
>
> ```
> npm install --save paper-input
> ```

No, that [`paper-input`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/paper-input) package is actually for React. The Polymer package is [`@polymer/paper-input`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@polymer/paper-input), so you would run:

```
npm install --save @polymer/paper-input
```

And your import usage is indeed correct (see [demo](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/messy-book?path=index.html:21:60)).

> I don't see a v3 element for `paper-input`

I assume you were looking at the [`paper-input`'s GitHub releases](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/releases), which does not include any versions newer than v2.2.3. However, there are in fact newer versions in NPM, but they're not tagged in GitHub for some reason. The element version compatible with Polymer 3.x is [`3.0.0-pre.21`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@polymer/paper-input/v/3.0.0-pre.21).

Comment: The only documentation that hints at that command is [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/about_30#whats-available) (docs are unfortunately lacking). The convention is to prefix the `@polymer` [scope](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope) for Polymer packages.

Comment: Thanks. At any rate, the installation worked, but now it throws this error... https://stackoverflow.com/q/51604096/1640892